# Why my browser shows loading spinner every minute/hr and affect all my tabs on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, firefox, chromium, browser, bug-reporting

Every minute or hr it shows a loading spinner on my screen even I'm using Mozilla Firefox or Chromium. When you're experience on it, everything on browser are immutable.
[browser with loading spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsKM1.png)

Here is the result when I run the free -m

```
     total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
```

Mem:       7879                      4904                     938                      277                2036                       2419

Swap:    2047                           61                     1986

Comment: "even I'm using Mozilla Firefox or Chromium" Both of those browsers can be running JavaScript which does consume system resources and therefore can slow things down..Also, what else is running? Please open a terminal and run `free -m` then highlight the result, copy it with Ctrl-Shift-C , come back here, click [edit] and paste the result into your question.

Comment: @K7AAY I just edited my question and add the result

Comment: Do you use an ad blocker extension?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, when the physical memory runs out, your swap memory get what it is overflown. It seems your swap area is too small for doing the job. I suggest increase your swap area. If you have an SSD, make a swapfile on it 6 GiB then it will be okay. In case you only have hard drives, it will be a little faster and safer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-swap-after-system-installation

Comment: Thank you for suggestion @SadaharuWakisaka

Comment: Since my answer didn't solve the problem. please create a new LiveUSB and test with it. Download Ubuntu's ISO file at https://ubuntu.com/download  Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu  . Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on another Linux PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu or on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows then reboot and choose the LiveUSB to boot from. Test Firefox and see if the problem repeats.

Comment: After, testing out on LiveUSB I didn't experience the loading spinner on the browser. So I decided to upgrade to 20.04 LTS. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please increase your swap file to at least 3GB
(and at least 11 GB if you added Hibernation to your Ubuntu)
as recommended by Ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Close all apps and open a terminal window. Run:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=3G count=8
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
grep SwapTotal /proc/meminfo
```

You should now see 3 GB of swap. You can change 3 in the second line of that command, to a larger value if you want, but no more than 16 GB.

Comment: I have question, where did swapfile get the total 3G? I have 120GB SSD for my main and 1TB HDD for my external. After running the commands above the Swaptotal that I got was 16GB not 3GB and you said it's fine to use 16GB for swapfile.

Comment: I alredy have 16GB free on my swap still the loading spinner shows

Comment: Then, we need to look elsewhere.