# Used gparted to resize partitions and now I’m stuck in the black screen on boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I’ve got a dual boot set up with Windows and Ubuntu on separate partitions. I wanted to give some of the free space on my Windows partition to the Ubuntu one.

I used `gparted` to make an empty partition with the extra space I wanted to give to Uubuntu. It didn’t work, and then the apps stopped working, so I restarted it. I was greeted with:

[image: this]

I don’t know exactly what “a start job is running” means, but I checked the UUID it shows there and it’s actually my EFI partition for Windows on sda1. Most of the other solutions on this site and Stack Overflow are for when this points to the swap, which it doesn’t.

Ok, so maybe I broke my Windows boot by resizing its partition, but why is that affecting my use of Ubuntu?

I’ve tried commenting out the line for that partition in `fstab`. That prevented the timer during startup but still landed me on the black screen.

I used `journalctl` and:

[image: this]

and:

[image: this]

showed up. I don’t have `nomodeset` in my `/etc/default/grub` file.
Windows won’t boot either.

I feel very stuck and can’t use my computer.

Comment: Can you boot Windows either in regular mode or in safe mode? You will need to fix the Windows partition from within Windows. Windows does not like it when you change the partition size using Ubuntu or any other OS.

Comment: Remove the Universal USB Installer device at first and try to change the USB port, then boot from the USB and Try Ubuntu Without Install. Have you tried [Boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)? You can also open terminal and do for your file system partition where it's at sda2 or change sda2 to be as at you `Sudo fsck /dev/sda2`

Comment: In my case I had the same sympthon and it was because I change my swap partition on other place and its UUID obviously changed. I was able to resolve it with this response: https://askubuntu.com/questions/33697/how-do-i-add-swap-after-system-installation