# Resuming Hibernate from a Swapfile

Tags: 12.04, hibernate

I am rather sure that I set up hibernation correctly, and that the swap file I am using is being recognized and written to when I click hibernate. (/hibernate.img)
In the corner of the screen, it says system snapshot, compression ratio, etc.

However, when I resume from hibernate, the top left corner reads "resuming from hibernate.img" but then the system just freezes. Every time.

Some of the tutorials mentioned using a specially compiled kernel, and I have not done this. The kernel is simply 3.2.0-25-generic.

I am using 12.04 64-bit. Any help would be great.

Comment: Sadly, chances are that the error does not lie within your setup. Hibernation has been disabled by default in Ubuntu 12.04 because it was very prone to errors. I've never gotten it to work reliably on my system.

Comment: It worked just fine with a swap partition. (when the two separate installations didn't conflict)

Comment: Full answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1132154/29219

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a swap file? In Linux you usually make a swap partition. That is a partition solely dedicated to function as swap memory. If you installed Ubuntu on a blank disk, you should have one by default. If you chose your own partition layout and didn't make one, I suggest repartitioning to have one.

The only issue I have encountered with hibernation so far is that if the swap partition is smaller than your physical RAM, hibernate always fails. Is the image file larger than your RAM or not?

Comment: it is smaller about 50%, but i was told that due to compression, that wouldn't be a problem. also I have dual-ubuntu installations and having one swap partition between the two leads to unbelievable complications.

Comment: If you want to hibernate both, you might want to try 2 swap partitions. A default installation will enable both swap partitions, but you can manually disable a swap partition to prevent one installed OS to corrupt the other's. You have to edit /etc/fstab to edit which swap files are used.