# fallocate vs dd for swapfile?

Tags: swap, dd

I'm wondering what the difference is between creating a swapfile with

```
fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
```

and

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=1024
```

both seem to work fine, but does one have an advantage over the other?

The only thing I could find online was that `fallocate` does not work on all file systems.

Comment: `fallocate` is usually faster (since it doesn't fill the created file with zeros) - otherwise no differences though, the end result is the same. See: https://antipaucity.com/2017/08/31/fallocate-vs-dd-for-swap-file-creation/

Comment: @JonasCz: Yes… but no! See muru’s answer.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From [the `mkswap` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/mkswap.8.html):

```
Note  that  a  swap  file  must  not contain any holes.  Using cp(1) to
create the file is not acceptable.  Neither is use of  fallocate(1)  on
file  systems  that support preallocated files, such as XFS or ext4, or
on copy-on-write filesystems like btrfs.   It  is  recommended  to  use
dd(1)  and  /dev/zero in these cases.  Please read notes from swapon(8)
before adding a swap file to copy-on-write filesystems.
```

And from [the `swapon` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/swapon.8.html):

```
You should not use swapon on a file with holes.  This can  be  seen  in
the system log as

      swapon: swapfile has holes.

The  swap file implementation in the kernel expects to be able to write
to the file directly, without the assistance of the  filesystem.   This
is  a problem on preallocated files (e.g.  fallocate(1)) on filesystems
like XFS or ext4, and on copy-on-write filesystems like btrfs.
```

It follows that, while `fallocate` may be faster than `dd`, it's not suitable for creating swap files and not supported by swap-related tools.

Comment: The mkswap manpage also says:  To set up a swap file, it is necessary to create that file before  initializing it with mkswap, e.g. using a command like `fallocate --length 8GiB swapfile` I'm confused.

Comment: @stumblebee and that will work fine on filesystems which don't support pre-allocated files where fallocate will essentially work like dd, but not on ext4, which is the default and by far the most commonly used Linux filesystem.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why `fallocate` would be a problem. It seems to, well, allocate the space. (As it says on the label.) And doing `fallocate -l 1g /swaptest &&  mkswap /swaptest && swapon /swaptest` on `ext4` doesn't complain about anything. `truncate -l 1g` would be different, since it just sets the file size but doesn't allocate any blocks.

Comment: From the `fallocate(1)` man page: For filesystems which support the fallocate system call, pre‐allocation is  done quickly **by *allocating* blocks** and marking them as uninitialized, …

Comment: So if it isn't doing that, someone needs to file a bug :)

Comment: @ilkkachu somebody has reproduced the problem on xfs, at least: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1129205

Comment: Interesting.  I've used fallocate on ext4 and xfs systems with no problems.  (Not that often, of course, since it's not a regular occurrence...)

Comment: Man pages have changed meanwhile. I'm not sure how to read that, but I think with Linux >=4.18 it might be ok to use fallocate for xfs http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man8/swapon.8.html

Answer (score 5):

Fallocate is faster, From [the fallocate manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/fallocate.1.html):

> **fallocate** is  used  to manipulate the allocated disk space for a file, either to deallocate or preallocate it.  **For filesystems which  support the  [fallocate system call](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man2/fallocate.2.html)**, preallocation is done quickly by allocating blocks and marking them as uninitialized, requiring no IO to  the  data blocks. This  is  much faster than creating a file by filling it with zeros.