# Can I have a swapfile on btrfs?

Tags: swap, btrfs

Modern Ubuntu versions are using a swap file instead of a swap partition by default.

Before the 5.0 Linux kernel it was not possible to place a swap file on a `btrfs` partition, `btrfs` file system could be damaged.

Now kernels support swap files on btrfs partitions. Can I use a swap file on Ubuntu installed on `btrfs` and what are possible problems?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is possible to use a swap file on `btrfs`, but there are some considerations that need taking care of.

`btrfs` filesystem doesn't let to create snapshots if there is a working swap file on the subvolume. That means that it is highly recommended to place a swap file on a separate subvolume.

Let's assume that the current swap is already off, the `/` is on `/dev/sda1` and Ubuntu is installed with `/` on `@` subvolume and `/home` is on `@home` subvolume.

1. Mount `/dev/sda1` to `/mnt`.

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   ```

   If you run `ls /mnt`, you'll see `@`, `@home` and other subvolumes that may be there.
2. Create a new `@swap` subvolume.

   ```
   sudo btrfs sub create /mnt/@swap
   ```
3. Unmount `/dev/sda1` from `/mnt`.

   ```
   sudo umount /mnt
   ```
4. Create `/swap` directory where we plan to mount the `@swap` subvolume.

   ```
   sudo mkdir /swap
   ```
5. Mount the `@swap` subvolume to `/swap`.

   ```
   sudo mount -o subvol=@swap /dev/sda1 /swap
   ```
6. Create the swap file.

   ```
   sudo touch /swap/swapfile
   ```
7. Set 600 permissions to the file.

   ```
   sudo chmod 600 /swap/swapfile
   ```
8. Disable COW for this file.

   ```
   sudo chattr +C /swap/swapfile
   ```
9. Set size of the swap file to 4G as an example.

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap/swapfile bs=1M count=4096
   ```
10. Format the swapfile.

    ```
    sudo mkswap /swap/swapfile
    ```
11. Turn the swap file on.

    ```
    sudo swapon /swap/swapfile
    ```

Now the new swap should be working.

You also need to update `/etc/fstab` to mount all this on boot. Add there two lines:

```
UUID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX /swap btrfs subvol=@swap 0 0
/swap/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

The `UUID` is the one of your `/dev/sda1`.

**Swap file can't be located on a btrfs raid of any sort.**

Comments and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please explain to us who have never tried btrfs: What is the alternatives to a swap file like this, and what is the advantage with this method compared to the alternatives?

Comment: If you simply have a swap file on btrfs, like installer creates by default, snapshots don't work. I mentioned this. This is the main purpose of moving it to another subvolume. One of the main reasons to use btrfs is snapshots capability.

Comment: Would it work to have a separate swap partition (alongside the btrfs partition) on the same drive?

Comment: No problem to have a swap partition, but the Ubuntu installer creates a swap file now. That makes trouble for people using snapshots and software like `timeshift`.

Comment: So it is the best alternative, when using btrfs, at least if no swap partition was created during the original partitioning? Or if the the user wants more swap?

Comment: The installer always creates a swap file unless manual partitioning is done. To be able to use snapshots you have options: don't use swap, have a swap partition, have a swap file on a separate subvolume. I explained how to make the latter.

Comment: Thanks ;-) I'm fine with your replies. Do you want to keep this conversation, or do you want me to delete my questions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103816/discussion-between-pilot6-and-sudodus).

Comment: I just tried now, and I'm getting an error: 

sudo swapon /swap/swapfile
swapon: /swap/swapfile: swapon failed: Invalid argument

I even made sure not to use `fallocate`.

Comment: @YamiYukiSenpai Are you usiing raid? You can't have a swap file on a raid.

Comment: nope.  I managed to solve it.  Had to start from scratch, and make sure that I disable copy-on-write before increasing the swapfile (or it was disable COW before creating the file).

Comment: https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Swapfile.html Now it's easier to make the swapfile. Using btrbk's option `archive_exclude /swap` I can back up. I didn't need to mount /dev/sda1 elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Note that for modern systems/laptops with NVME SSDs, you have `/dev/nvme0n1p2` instead of `/dev/sda1` and you should ignore /dev/nvme0n1p1 because that is your efi boot disk that your OS created when you installed it.

In addition it should be recommended to add two mount options 'defaults' and 'noatime'. Defaults will automatically load the mount options for the drive (SSD, HDD). Noatime will prevent files being written if only opened:

```
UUID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX /swap btrfs defaults,noatime,subvol=@swap 0 0
/swap/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: `noatime` isn't necessary as `relatime` is the default and that also won't write unless the file has been written to. This hasn't been a thing for ~15 years since the kernel changed the default to it. I'm not certain you need defaults, or if a swapfile benefits from `lazytime` or `compress`. It probably would though.

Comment: `defaults` doesn't make any sense if there are other options. It is used if nothing else is there.

Answer (score 3):

The popular answer is correct except that you should ***not*** use fallocate(1) to allocate space to the swapfile.  It can create file-system 'holes' which are incompatible with swapfile usage (swap needs 100% contiguous space since a filesystem is not used within the swap space).
You should use 'dd if=/dev/zero ...' instead.
See the answer on this thread:  [fallocate vs dd for swapfile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017309/fallocate-vs-dd-for-swapfile)
The mkswap(8) and swapon(8) manpages both explicitly discourage the use of fallocate(1) to instantiate a swapfile on the filesystem.

Comment: Yes but the answer in that link only creates a 1Mb swap file. To create say a 8Gb one, you need to do "sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap/swapfile bs=1M count=8192"

Comment: I changed from allocate to dd.

Comment: Is this still true? The btrfs docs use `fallocate` in their example: https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Swapfile.html

Answer (score 2):

If your partition is encrypted (LUKS), the mount point is on `/dev/mapper` for example:

```
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p5_crypt /swap btrfs defaults,noatime,subvol=@swap 0 0
/swap/swapfile none swap sw 0 0 here
```

To get the `uuids` run the `blkid` command:

```
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p5_crypt: UUID="06c8c73c-1cc4-477b-a687-6c21697d645d"   UUID_SUB="7f884b26-d76e-49db-9959-311fa2a5dd20" TYPE="btrfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="8090a824-63fa-4087-a948-89cca1a369cd" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="887ff27b-01"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="46405308-2ed1-40f3-a86b-906f1118970b" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="887ff27b-05"
```

And then replace the `mapper` location with the specific `uuid`

```
UUID=06c8c73c-1cc4-477b-a687-6c21697d645d /swap btrfs   defaults,noatime,subvol=@swap 0 0 
/swap/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a swap on btrfs, if you take care what the btrfs doku tell about this:

```
filesystem - must be only single device
filesystem - must have only single data profile
swapfile - the containing subvolume cannot be snapshotted
swapfile - must be preallocated (i.e. no holes)
swapfile - must be NODATACOW (i.e. also NODATASUM, no compression)
```

For more information see the source:

- https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Swapfile.html

Answer (score 2):

Since version 6.1 it’s possible to create the [swapfile in a single command](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-man5.html#swapfile-support).

I will try to test the implications of the following (like should a btrfs swapfile be mounted in a swapfile subvolume so that the snapshots can still be performed on the parent volume?)

Note snapshot is not supported on subvolumes containing swapfiles because the following snapshot requirement

```
subvolume - cannot be snapshotted if it contains any active swapfiles
```

> Use a default value of 8G but if it's already set then use what was set

```
btr_swap_size=${btr_swap_size:=8G}
btrfs subvolume create SWAP
btrfs filesystem mkswapfile --size btr_swap_size /SWAP/swapfile
swapon /swapfile
```

a mini script

```
btr_swap_size=${btr_swap_size:=8G}
btr_swap_subvolume=${btr_swap_subvolume:="/SWAP"}
btr_swap_file=${btr_swap_subvolume}/SWAP-"${btr_swap_size}".img
swapon -s|grep -q "$swapfile" /etc/fstab
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
# if not then create it
    echo '$swapfile not found. Adding $swapfile.'

    btrfs subvolume create ${btr_swap_subvolume}
    btrfs filesystem mkswapfile --size "${btr_swap_size}" "${btr_swap_file}"
    swapon "${btr_swap_file}"
    echo '/$swapfile none swap defaults 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
else
    echo '$swapfile found. No changes made.'
fi
```

Comment: I think you can create a subvolume and make a swap there by this command.

Comment: I honestly didn't see that I repeated https://askubuntu.com/a/1457889/59660's conditions when I wrote this but I want to give a pasteable answer so hopefully I'll ad some value with this answer...

Comment: There are some mistakes. `btrfs subvolume create SWAP` won't work without specifying a device. Also you need to mount it.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer didn't work for me. I got error:

```
$ sudo swapon -v --show /swap/swapfile
```

> swapon: /swap/swapfile: swapon failed: Invalid argument

for me work solution was from https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-man5.html#swapfile-support

```
# cd /swap
# truncate -s 0 swapfile
# chattr +C swapfile
# fallocate -l 2G swapfile
# chmod 0600 swapfile
# mkswap swapfile
# swapon swapfile
```

/etc/fstab:

```
/swap/swapfile              none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: This answer doesn't look correct. it is unclear where the swap file is located. Is it `/swapfile` or `/swap/swapfile`?

Comment: /swap/swapfile on the dedicated subvolume