# What does the "@" symbol mean when in front of a directory, e.g. "@home"?

Tags: mount, swap, btrfs

I am trying to follow another post on Ask Ubuntu ([Can I have a swapfile on btrfs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206157/can-i-have-a-swapfile-on-btrfs), specifically [Pilot's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1206161/618353)) and I have run into the problem that I have no idea what `@home` means. The paragraph  I'm confused by is below:

> Lets assume that the current swap is already off, the `/` is on `/dev/sda1` and Ubuntu is installed with `/` on `@` subvolume and `/home` is on `@home` subvolume.

I am not sure what *"`/home` is on `@home`"*, or even *"`/` is on `/dev/sda1`"* and *"`/` on `@`"* mean.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. The `@` refers to [a subvolume](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Subvolumes.html), which is one of the key aspects of the file system 

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thank you. I'd never seen that before (probably because I'd never messed around with the file system before). Anyways, I managed to figure out the rest of the answer on that post I linked. For posterity, the problem I was having was that I was using /dev/nvme0n1p2  instead of /dev/nvme0n1p3 to represent my ssd

Comment: @matigo, the use of @ in he context of btrfs subvolumes is, afaik, just a convention, used by Ubuntu (and perhaps Debian), but for example not on Fedora. You can use the character to name a subvolume as you can use it in a directory name.

Comment: @vanadium good to know. Thank you 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `@` symbol doesn't have any special meaning. `@home` is just a name of a btrfs subvolume. It can be named differently.

Ubuntu maintainers chose to name `@` subvolume to mount `/` and `@home` to mount `/home`. I followed the same logic and chose to call a subvolume for a swap file `@swap`.