# s2disk works, but hibernation from menu gets stuck afer login

Tags: xubuntu, power-management, 18.04, systemd, hibernate

Running Xubuntu 18.04 LTS, I've set up hibernation with `uswsusp`, and it works flawlessly (`s2disk`).

Then, I've integrated `s2disk` to Systemd  (`systemctl hibernate`) by overriding the `systemd-hibernate` service to

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStartPre=-/bin/run-parts -v -a pre /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/s2disk
ExecStartPost=-/bin/run-parts -v --reverse -a post /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep
```

As expected, `sudo systemctl hibernate` works without any issues.

The problem appears when clicking the hibernate button on the power menu (enabled via polkit) fails - it looks like it worked, but when resuming the system freezes completely upon login.

I suspect that the button does not actually run the same commands as the other methods, but I couldn't find how to set it.

**Update**: This seems to be machine-specific. I have another PC, with very similar setup (same Xubuntu version and hibernation configuration - from [here](https://churchman.nl/2017/05/27/hibernation-and-hybrid-sleep-on-ubuntu-17-04-gnome-3-24/)). On the other PC, it works correctly, but for the machine in question (it's a laptop), it still does not.

**Update 2**: I've tried to restart Plymouth upon resume (this is a solution to similar issues I've found), but it didn't help.

Comment: It _should_ run the same commands via logind's bus methods. Did you make your service `Type=oneshot`? No idea why that should matter, though.

Comment: Yes, it is `oneshot`. Just to clarify, `sudo systemctl hibernate` works as expected (no freezing at login or anything). Only from the XFCE powr dialog, the issue appears.

Comment: Would be creating a `.desktop` file on your desktop be a suitable solution?

Comment: @Fabby It's not a bad idea, but I want to specifically make the hibernate button on the power menu work. So.. no.

Comment: Give some comments on the laptop model and hardware, so we can see if there are any compatibility issues.

Comment: It's Samsung [NP350V5C](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/pcs/NP350V5C-T01US-specs) with Radeon 70xxm graphics

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot (like me) to specify the `resume` & `resume_offset` Linux boot parameters? Without the `resume_offset` I had nearly the same problem: black screen on "`s2disk: Returned to userspace`" message.

I've written [here a full answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1132154/29219) to be able to resume from a swap file.