# I hibernated my PC, but it has not able to resume it. (Ubuntu 18.10)

Tags: login-screen, 18.10, ubuntu-gnome

I used this syntax:

```
sudo hibernate
```

And after sometime, when I pressed the power button and waited. This message is on the screen for like half an hour but no sign of login  appearance.

```
s2disk: Snapshotting system
s2disk: Returned to userspace
```

It used to work differently before by showing 0 to 100% rate of resuming window. But now, it's different. *What should I do now? Can I get my PC back? Should I never use hibernation from now? Has something changed in new updates?*

> Update: After a while, I used Ctrl+Alt+F1 to login, and reboot my PC. But I really want to use hibernation next time. Because this is not a appropriate solution.

Comment: Did you follow this https://askubuntu.com/a/892410/29219 this https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation/Hibernate_Without_Swap_Partition and perhaps this https://askubuntu.com/q/1035345/29219 ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot (like me) to specify the `resume` & `resume_offset` Linux boot parameters? Without the `resume_offset` I had the same problem as you: black screen on "`s2disk: Returned to userspace`" message.

I've written [here a full answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1132154/29219) to be able to resume correctly from a swap file.