# Hibernation is causing laptop to shutdown

Tags: shutdown, swap, hibernate

I managed to increase my swapfile to 16GB because i want to hibernate my laptop.

I tried with `sudo systemctl hibernate` but it's not working. The laptop is shutting down.

Comment: So far so good. The intersting part is when you start up the laptop again. Does it resume or does it boot normally? Also include which steps you take to make it work ( e.g. did you follow this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file )

Comment: It boots normally. POST and then ubuntu logo. Also yea i followed this guide, but no luck :(