# How to boot from Hibernation with 2 Swap files in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, swap, hibernate

i have 16GiB of RAM installed on my system and i have 2 disks in laptop, running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

i have googled

> **How to enable hibernate mode in Ubuntu 18.04** ~(which is slightly
>   different from previous versions of Ubuntu)

I got the answer, i have enabled the same way by using this command
**`sudo systemctl hibernate`**
and adding 
**`resume=UUID<uuid of swap>`** in grub menu.
But my problem is i have **2 Swap files** , and i dont know how to add both of UUIDS in grub menu.

Comment: You will also need to determine the offset of the swapfile within the partition specified by the UUID - see [https://askubuntu.com/a/1132154/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/1132154/283721) - but I think that you may be restricted to using a single swap file for the hibernation.

Comment: Could you put a link to the "how to enable..." in your question above?

Comment: @charles-green i think the offset is used to make swapfile more accurate to read. and it is not necessary to add offset. what do you say?

Comment: No, the UUID identifies the partition that the swapfile resides on, and the offset tells systemd where on the partition to look for the swapfile.

Comment: @CharlesGreen thankyou for your information.

Comment: I'll be interested in how well it works for you - I gave up doing hibernation after the 4th or 5th time my disk got corrupted.

Comment: its worked fine for me 3 times and than i got some problems with CuDnn drivers (that are working fine in ANN but not for CNN) im noob in this deep-learning setups. so im going to refresh install ubuntu 18 and that would be Mate(flavour) this time.