# Enabling Hibernate option on XUbuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, shutdown, hibernate

I have installed XUbuntu.

```
xxx:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I would like to hibernate (instead of shutdown or suspend) my workstation sometimes. However, the options available are only: Log Out, Restart, Shutdown and Suspend. Is there a way of enabling the Hibernate Option? or is there a way of Hibernate the system using the command line?

I have been reading [this StackOverflow question and answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file/1132154#1132154). However, I do not know if I want to use my swap file. Is there an easy solution that saves the content of the RAM within the hard disk of the system? Or, better said, is there an easy solution for enabling the option like in Windows? I do not really want to have control over which part of the system the OS saves the information. It useless until I have more than enough space.

Note:

```
xxx:~$ sudo systemctl hibernate
Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb not supported
```

Answer (score 3):

You must reconfigure your system to add Hibernation. It is not part of the standard configuration, and does not work with all PC hardware.

First, hibernation requires increasing your swap space to preserve the system state. See column three at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_much_swap_do_I_need.3F

Next, Secure Boot must be [disabled in the PC's BIOS](https://askubuntu.com/a/870532/197910).

Then, take a look at https://askubuntu.com/a/821122/197910 and [how to add it to the Action Buttons](https://askubuntu.com/a/276686/197910).

Please also note Hibernation can be troublesome on a dual-boot machine. Hibernation locks out write access to files; if you Hibernate out of an OS, the other OS can't reliably access the files of the first OS.

Comment: +1, it will take a while for me to read and test everything. Thank you