# Ubuntu 20.04LTS diskpartitioning

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I'm doing a clean re install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS  my previous install had been created with LVM  which I want to avoid as it cost me tons of lost data before.
starting situation 
Disk1 = SSD 120GB
Disk2 = 2 TB HDD

wanted situation :
Disk1 :   <s>/swap disk 16 GB</s> 
/    : root (bootable) with Ubuntu system
/ application software + config files
/ downloads application software
Disk2  :  /home(?)  
/ application data
/ user data  files
/swap disk 16 GB 

How do I use the partitioning

Comment: from other articles I figured out that the swap should be on the HDD

Comment: Read [Is it necessary to have a /home and /swap partitions in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1234843/931617).

Comment: From the looks of this proposed partition scheme, I suspect whatever problems you've blamed on LVM are misdirected, because this kind of overpartitioning is a mess... I suggest keeping everything on one partition unless you have a very good reason to keep `/home` separate.  And `/home` is the only one I would even consider putting on another partition.  Put your root file system on the drive with the faster R/W and use the second disk to store data (pics, docs, music, video)

Comment: My system would be ~500MB EFI as Fat32, /root about 40+GBs as ext4 on SSD and /home on HDD as ext4.  Keep it simple.  Have a good backup system in place for when things happen.  Can also just have /root on SSD and use HDD for backups, if you do not think you will have a lot of data.

Comment: @Nmath re my remarks about LVM : please don't draw nay conclusions about my  LVM remarks from my proposed setup,  , FYI  my reluctance on LVM was  double HD non raid system, where the second  -disk which imho was still empty-  had a hickup and all data on all disks was in accessible.   LVM config  adds a layer that make the data fysically unreachable and unreadable  

I have no confidence in LVM  i want my data fysically readable when i connect my drive through a SATA interface or through a SATA-USB interface

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity  if I understand correctly from the linked article <br>
a- FROM 18.04 LTS onward -  I can ditch the swap partition  because it creates a swapfile on the  / partition  
b- if I put the /home partition on the HDD,   any other application software is also stored / installed   on the HDD,  not only data
that raises other questions :  how about  VMware of Virtualbox  how can    
b-

Comment: Would i be an alternative de create the follwing directory structure <br>
 Disk 1  SSD :  /     root (bootable) with ubuntu system software
                        /home  with application software and application data 
Disk 2 HDD  / data   with  user data files

Comment: @DerekGiroulle a) that's right b) I'm not sure I understand: `/home` partition is for storing your personal data, applications won't install there. The applications will install in disk 1 where the root system will be installed (`/`).

Comment: You should put `/home` on your SSD.  That's where a lot of configs are stored that are often referenced during startup and application launches. Your system performance will suffer as a result of putting your home directory on a slower drive. Especially random read speed which is dramatically worse on HDDs and the type that matters most in these cases.  No idea what you're on about with LVM - but it seems irrelevant here

Comment: @DerekGiroulle  Do not try to complicate partitions, just leads to headaches.  Use the KISS system.  Just need an EFI and /root partition, if a lot of data add /home to HDD.

Comment: And don't try to move applications. Leave them where they are installed. Many won't work if you relocate them...

Comment: Summarising the advice :  <br>
-- Disk 1 SSD : / root (bootable) with ubuntu system software  <br>
                         /home with application software and application data <br>
                     no /swap  partition unless i want to hibernate 
--- Disk 2 HDD /data with user data files <br>

that would also be a setup useful for a laptop with an internal SSD and an external (USB)  HDD  with data that could move between different laptops with an equivalent setup 

Thanks for the advice

Comment: This last setup works for me