# Swapfile for hibernation but no hibernation option/button in kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, swap, hibernate

Hello I am using Kubuntu and I want to be able to use "Power management" options for hibernation but they are not available.

I followed the highest rated post by Anthony O. from:
[Hibernate and resume from a swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file)

I am now able to use(but no button inside KDE shows hibernation):

```
$ sudo systemctl hibernate
```

Below I have general information as it might help

```
$ swapon
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file  16G   0B   -2
    
$ sudo findmnt -no SOURCE,UUID -T /swapfile
[sudo] password for daniel: 
/dev/nvme0n1p5 efcdc047-679c-427f-a607-daf3ebaceb05

$ sudo swap-offset /swapfile
resume offset = 34816
```

```
GNU nano 4.8               /etc/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service.d/.#override.conf6f9ccc51812d3882                         
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/s2disk
ExecStartPost=/bin/run-parts -a post /lib/systemd/system-sleep
```

```
GNU nano 4.8                                              /etc/default/grub                                                        
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=UUID=efcdc047-679c-427f-a607-daf3ebaceb05 resume_offset=34816 quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

```
GNU nano 4.8                                     /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume                                      Modified  
RESUME=UUID=efcdc047-679c-427f-a607-daf3ebaceb05 resume_offset=34816
# Resume from /swapfile
```

Comment: It is Kubuntu 20.04

Comment: "options for hibernation but they are not available"- You mean the button for hibernate isn't available?

Comment: Hello kortewegdevries yes