# Ubuntu 20.04 - system cannot hibernate despite dealing with swapfile

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, swap, hibernate

#### General description

I want to switch from Windows to Linux, but there is one issue which doesn't allow me to use my Ubuntu 20.04 fully. I don't know how to make my computer hibernate. As I already learned, the problem is common and many answers can be found, but any of them helped me.

#### To summarise my hardware:

1. HP 250 G7 laptop with windows 10 on it and Ubuntu 20.04 (dual boot)
2. 256 GB SSD, where about 150 GB is for Windows partition and about 90 GB for Linux (56 GB unused), 16 GB RAM

#### What I get as a result of `sudo hibernate` and `sudo pm-hibernate`

It depends. Before I could hibernate but only if I had small usage of RAM (not anymore). Sometimes the screen is black for a while and then comes back, sometimes I get a message: "hibernate:Warning: Tuxonice binary signature file not found."

#### What I've tried

1. Swap partition. If swapfile is enought, I would prefer to stick with it - I don't have good experience playing around with partition dividing. Anyway, I tried to make a swap partition, but when I try to resize my main Linux partition (to get free space) the "Resize" button is greyed out and in the partition info there is "Minimum size - 90630 MB, Maximum size - 90630 MB" which looks like this partition cannot be resized)
2. I downloaded pm-utils package
3. I created a swapfile from scratch following this video -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSbBl31ohjE&list=LL&index=1
4. I followed highest scored answer in this thread -> [Hibernate and resume from a swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file)
5. Swap file. I followed this -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coiPtCFnO-0&list=LL&index=2&t=78s video to copy UUID of my swapfile to `/etc/default/grub`
6. And some other tutorials, but everything is about creating swap file/partition and copy-pasting UUID into `/etc/default/grub`

#### Content of my system files

In my `/etc/default/grub` file I have this line:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="resume=UUID=158230dd-7ba1-4065-af7c-d1e0964c2fd5 resume_offset=8568832 quiet splash"`

When typing `swapon` I get `NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO /swapfile file  12G   0B   -2`

My swapfile is less than RAM, but I don't use the whole RAM while testing, so I think it's not the problem.

Please help, as it's the only reason why I'm still on Windows xD

Comment: I think you will find that your swapfile has to be equal to or larger in size than your RAM. It doesn’t matter how much is in use at the time

Comment: I changed the size to make sure. My RAM is 16GB, I made swap file 33GB. All is the same after changes.