# How to Hibernate on Ubuntu 22.04 if I have a swap file?

Tags: lubuntu, swap, hibernate, 22.04

I can not hibernate Ubuntu 22.04 because:

1. "Leave" --> "Hibernate" button does nothing. I do not know why Ubuntu developers include this button.
2. Calling `systemctl hibernate` shutdowns system completely.
3. I've [read](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file) that I can install **uswsusp**, but **uswsusp** is deprecated in Ubuntu 22.04

I use Lubuntu 22.04. Also I use a swap file (I do not know whether using a swap file affects my possibility to hibernate). My RAM is 8 Gb and my swap file is 20 Gb.

Comment: Does your machine meet the requirements for hibernate to function?  For starters it requires you to have a *swapfile* larger than your RAM, which a default install of Lubuntu 22.04 LTS does not provide.  See [this article on Lubuntu's discourse](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-create-a-swapfile-in-lubuntu-20-04-20-10/1959) for details on creating a swapfile (*or increasing size*)

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu is a *small* team & thus features like *Hibernate* put in menus etc by upstream LXQt are left in even though they won't work for all installs, as it's thus easier for those users who want the feature to enable.  Upstream Canonical/Ubuntu are aware *hibernate* does not work on all hardware, but again it's left in for those who's hardware supports it. If more people would step up & help improve our testing/code, it'd work on more hardware than it does currently - but it's only tested on hardware owned by QA-testers etc.

Comment: @guiverc I've updated my question to include information about swap file size. Yes, swap file size more than x2 large than RAM size.