# How can I enable hibernate on Ubuntu 22.04 using a swapfile?

Tags: 22.04, power-management, swap, hibernate

how can I enable hibernation on my newly installed Ubuntu? I have a swapfile of 18 GB, and my RAM is 16, I didn't make a swap partition when installing the OS, and now I searched everywhere and I can't find a proper tutorial on this matter, I would appreciate some guidance on this topic or maybe someone can walk me through the process.
Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu installation does not make a swap partition any more. My understanding is you will need to create a swap partition for hibernate. However, hibernate and Ubuntu do not work on all hardware. So it may not work even if you create a swap partition.

Comment: Did you setup LVM and or hard disk encryption while installing Ubuntu? Add this information in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate and resume from a swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file)