# LUbuntu 22.04.04 - hibernate not working - acpi error couldn't enable sleep button event

Tags: boot, lubuntu, hibernate

When I click on Leave / Hibernate there is no action when I confirm the dialogue.

settings:

- swap file (4GB) 2x physical memory (2GB)
  note: file, no swap partition
- Secure Boot is disabled
  bios: HP Pavilion X2 detachable
  bios F.20 (seems to be latest)
  TPM Device: hidden
  secure boot: disabled
  platform key: enrolled
  boot order: UEFI Boot order, bios doesn't show legacy boot order

However on boot I get an acpi error couldn't enable sleep button event message. Because I can't update bios (seems to be latest version) I tried without success:

- load bios default
- sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub none of these option changed boot error:

#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=strict"

#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"

#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pnpacpi=off"

sudo update-grub

sudo update-initramfs -u

I don't know if the acpi error is related to the system not hibernating.

Your help would be very much appreciated because I don't want to try out something that could result in boot failure.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file (answer 22.04) which enables hibernate but resume results in a black screen after the LUbuntu logo. Any ideas?

Comment: changed swap file to swap partition (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) causes the same result:  It enables hibernate but resume results in a black screen after the LUbuntu logo